# React-profiler: element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs

based on [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html) and [this medium article](https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/how-to-use-reacts-experimental-new-profiler-feature-c340674e5d0e), I did something as simple as this to try profiler in react

```
import React, { unstable_Profiler as Profiler }  from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

   logProfile = (id, phase, actualTime, baseTime, startTime, commitTime) => {
    console.log(`${id}'s ${phase} phase:`);
    console.log(`Actual time: ${actualTime}`);
    console.log(`Base time: ${baseTime}`);
    console.log(`Start time: ${startTime}`);
    console.log(`Commit time: ${commitTime}`);
};

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      <Profiler id="app" onRender={this.logProfile}>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
      </Profiler>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

but this is throwing following error

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
>   components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
>   undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
>   it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I face the same issue and I change the import object from `unstable_Profiler` to `Profiler` directly and it works.

```js
// import React, { unstable_Profiler as Profiler }  from 'react';
import React, { Profiler }  from 'react';

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Profiler>
      <OtherComponents />
    </Profiler>
  </div>
)
```

I check the test scenario of Profiler [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/86b4070ddb6bd2fcf22c904cfff07a04696b9495/packages/react/src/__tests__/ReactProfiler-test.internal.js) at github.